# How do I grab an element and a class with selenium (Python)?

Tags: python, selenium, testing, automation

I'm trying to do some automation testing where I will need to grab an element to choose the right quality video. The problem here is that I tried CSS Selector, Class Name, and XPath and nothing is working as I want it.

Does anyone know a better way to choose the quality of a video inside by using selenium and python?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from random import * 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException
import threading
import time
from idlelib import browser


def get_driver_and_webpage():  
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--incognito")
    #chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    #chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox') 
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= "C:\\Program files (x86)\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)
    browser.get('https://ampdemo.azureedge.net/azuremediaplayer.html?url=%2F%2Famssamples.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net%2F49b57c87-f5f3-48b3-ba22-c55cfdffa9cb%2FSintel.ism%2Fmanifest&muted=true&aes=true&wallClockDisplayEnabled=true&useLocalTimeZone=true')
    wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)

    browserr = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
        (By.CLASS_NAME, "vjs-menu-content")))
    cclick = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
        (By.CLASS_NAME, "aria-lebel")))
    browser.click()
    time.sleep(randint(10, 15))
    browser.clear()
    time.sleep(randint(10, 15))
    cclick.click()
    print("search-cclick has been clicked")
    time.sleep(randint(15, 20))

    time.sleep(200)
    browser.quit()      

Number = 1   # Number of browsers to be open
thread_list = list()

for i in range(Number):
    t = threading.Thread(name='Test {}'.format(i), target=get_driver_and_webpage)
    t.start()
    time.sleep(1)
    print(t.name + ' started!')
    thread_list.append(t)

for thread in thread_list:
    thread.join()

    print('Testing is completed and done')
```

Comment: CSS Selector or the XPath would probably be your best bet... do you have an example of the page that you're trying to pull from? *Edit:* it's a public page. My bad. What element are you trying to pull?

Comment: Which element? Which line? What error do you see?

Comment: I think he's going for something like this CSS selector: `div.amp-quality-control li[aria-checked='true']`

Comment: does he need to hover to display the elements before attempting a click?

Comment: yeah, he will, probably.

Comment: This is the element that I would like to get <li class="vjs-menu-item amp-menu-item" tabindex="-1" role="menuitemcheckbox" aria-live="off" aria-label="816p-6Mbps" aria-checked="false">816p-6Mbps<span class="vjs-control-text"> </span></li>

Comment: Also, I tried to get the XPATH //*[@id="azuremediaplayer"]/div/div[7]/div[3]/div[3]/div/ul/li[3] to make sure I can do that directly, but it doesn't do anything

Comment: I did it with node.js but I don't know if selenium is a little bit picky or not!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read the question and the page correctly, you can read content of the element from this CSS query to see the selected quality:

```
div.amp-quality-control li[aria-checked='true']
```

You can use the CSS query without the `aria-checked='true'` to look for the available qualities reported by the page"

```
div.amp-quality-control li
```

Comment: video = webDriverWait"document.getElementsByClassName('vjs-menu-item')[4].click();"
 #video2 = "document.querySelector('[aria-label=\"816p-6Mbps\"]').click();"
    driver.execute_script(video)